# PHP and MVC Navigation Menu Bug - Menu Does not Change On Login, but does on refresh

Tags: php, model-view-controller, menu, navigationbar

I am currently working on a side project for a web application. I am using PHP and trying to follow an MVC type of pattern (not using any frameworks), and I am not able to get the menus in my navigation bar to display properly. The intended function is that the user will get to the site and login with their information. Each user has a level of permissions that drives the kind of navigation menus they have access to see.

The way that I have the site working right now, is that when the user logs in, it puts their username and their permissions level into the $_SESSION global. The default layout (layout.php) responsible for showing the navigation is then brought into the page via require_once, after it does a check to see what kind of navigation menu should be used. For all purposes, the setup is working, just not how I want. After login, the navigation menu stays the same until the page is refreshed or a menu option is chosen.

I've tried to trace the problem but being newer to PHP and even newer to MVC I can't quite figure out where to fix the issue. I know that layout.php is rendering every time the controller selects a view. Somehow the role in the $_SESSION global has to be set before this renders but after the login controller is finished. I've tried to do page refreshes through PHP and JavaScript but it is a perpetual refresh (keeps looping) and even though it would be a quick fix it doesn't feel like the right one. Hoping someone might be able to think of something I haven't or point me in the right direction. Here are the code snippets for the code that is being used during the login process.

index.php - This is the "front" of the site, where everything starts from and where a user lands.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && array_key_exists("username", $_SESSION)) {
    session_destroy();
} else {
    session_start();
}

require_once('connection.php');

if (isset($_GET['controller'])) {
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];

    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
    } else {
        $action = 'index';
    }
} else {
    $controller = 'login';
    $action = 'login';
}

require_once('views/layout.php');
```

layout.php

```
<?php
    $nav = "";             
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && array_key_exists("username", $_SESSION)) {
        if ($_SESSION['role'] == 1) {
            $nav = "admin_nav.php";
        } else if ($_SESSION['role'] == 2) {
            $nav = "prof_nav.php";
        } else if ($_SESSION['role'] == 3) {
            $nav = "student_nav.php";
        } else {
            $nav = "guest_nav.php";
        }
    } else {
        $nav = "default_nav.php";
    }           
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Auto-Grader</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/site.css">
    </head>

    <body>    
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-top">
            </div>
            <div id="header-bottom">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navigation-wrapper">
            <?php require_once($nav); ?>
        </div>        

        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <?php require_once('routes.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <footer>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The login controller

```
class LoginController {
    public function login() {
        require_once('views/login/index.php');
    }

    public function validateLogin() {
        require_once('models/login_validator.php');

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $isValid = LoginValidator::validateLogin($email, $password);

        $username = $isValid['username'];

        if ($isValid) {
            # Show home/landing page view
            require_once('views/home/index.php');
        } else {
            require_once('views/login/failure.php');
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['role']);
        session_destroy();
        # Redirect to homepage on logout
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('index.php') </script>";
    }
}
```

The login model (where the $_SESSION global is first set)

```
class LoginValidator {

    public static function validateLogin($email, $password) {
        $db = Db::getInstance();

        $userQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND pwd = :password');
        $userQuery->execute(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));

        $user = $userQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!$user) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
            $_SESSION['role'] = $user['perm_id'];
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any input, if there are other pieces that need to be seen, I'd be happy to edit the post and provide them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trace the execution through your application. If the session var is set after the navigation is created then it will not work. If so, you need to process any post events before you create the view.

You have an error in the following code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && array_key_exists("username", $_SESSION)) {
    session_destroy();
} else {
    session_start();
}
```

`session_start` populates the `$_SESSION` super global so the first conditional can never return true.